# How to configure connection timeout in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate v4.1.4.final.jar using Java 1.7 to connect to Oracle 10g server. And this is a standalone java program.

Unfortunately, my query takes more than 30 minutes to run. I want to know where I can configure connection time out & read time out so that while running this standalone program, it will not time out and throw error?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the _DataSource/Connection_ for Hibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options that you can try:

1. If the jdbc driver that you use support timeout function and can be configured through property, then you can pass on the property using: `hibernate.connection.<propertyname>`
2. Use external connection provider such as ***c3p0*** or ***DBCP***, and control the timeout as those external provider support.
3. Configure your hibernate to use `DataSource` instead of plain `Connection` and control timeout through that.

The closest property that I can find for [Oracle driver](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/pool/OracleDataSource.html#getConnectionProperties__) is `oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout` property. So in your hibernate configuration, the whole name will be `hibernate.connection.oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout`..hope this works for you.

Comment: DJ, I'm using Oracle JDBC driver called ojdbc14.jar for Oracle 10g. Do you have a code snippet to use timeout from this Jar?

Comment: What would be the equivalent for postgres?

Comment: @faizan, you need to find out from postgres's driver documentation, and apply the same rules as I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By default it won't throw any kind of error, FWIW...if you run a query, it'll just work, AFAIK.

In terms of connect timeout, you may be able to specify in your

`hibernate.connection.url` a particular option for your DB, ex: Postgres I'd [add](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/connect.html) `&connectTimeout=0`